# mingw-w64 on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, mingw, build-process, cross-compiling

I am searching for a ubuntu package.

Is there any way to get the x86_64-mingw-w64-gcc compiler in version 4.9 on ubuntu 14.04?

In the official repositorys you only find mingw-w64 in version 3.1 which comes with mingw-w64-gcc in version 4.8

i'm searching for 2 days now, but i can find neither a package nor sources to build it myself.

there are packages for arch linux and on debian/testing, but i think they don't work for ubuntu.

it is gonna be a cross compiler for windows 7 64 bit.